# android studio error in R.java file

Tags: java, android-studio

Whenever I run my project in android studio I get the following error:

```
"Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details."
```

how can i solve it?

Comment: `Build > Clean project` followed by `Build > Rebuild project` ... But you should really show those errors.

Comment: Actually i got an error in the file named R.java which is auto generated by Android Studio and the error was 'an integer was assigned to another integer' .i.e.the error was  "int 5=1.7284539;"  .since the file is auto-generated,the changes i make has no effect on that file and the changes disappear when i rebuild the code.

Comment: Same error here. Have you solve it?